# Animate a diagonally-scrolling background pattern in Flutter

Tags: scroll, flutter

Flutter newbie here.

Basically I'd like to reproduce the effect of the background in this video:

https://youtu.be/LcCtg1D_RIE?t=804

From what I have gathered so far, I can use a Stack widget to set some background layer, and use the repeat property of Image to get a repeating tile pattern. The following code does this reasonably well:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          width: 5000,
          height: 5000,
          child: Image.network(
            "https://www.scirra.com/images/articles/daf.png",
            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
          )),
       /* UI goes here */
   ]);
```

What I cannot figure out, is how to perform the animation. I have tried various scroll classes (like SingleChildScrollView) but they seem more designed for interactive use and do not allow bi-directional scrolling.

Another idea I have explored is providing a translation matrix to my Container, but while this indeed scrolls the pattern, it also leaves a black area at the edge of the screen.

I'm sure there exists a smart trick to easily achieve that effect - would someone have some clever input?

Comment: Probably the best suited way to build an animation like that would be to use SingleTickerStateProvider (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) with a StatefulWidget. Wrap your Container in a Positioned widget and use the AnimationController to animate the position values of the container.

Comment: Ah, Positioned is the part I have missed! This works nicely. All I have to do is to modulo the Ticker's duration to the image's dimensions and set the top and left of the Positioned to be <= 0.0, and the effect is perfect! Thanks a lot for the pointer!